# Div text looks different

Tags: javascript, html

I have two similar codes:

First one:

```
function DisplayLoadingDiv() {
    document.getElementById("steamdiv").style.display = "";
    var newobj = document.createElement("h1");
    newobj.className = "loadingtext";
    newobj.innerHTML = "<span>L</span>" +
         "<span>o</span>" + 
         "<span>a</span>" +
         "<span>d</span>" + 
         "<span>i</span>" + 
         "<span>n</span>" +
         "<span>g</span>";
    document.getElementById("steamdiv").appendChild(newobj);
}
```

Second one:

```
<button id="steambutton" class="button">Get Phishers</button>
    <div id="steamdiv">
    <h1 class="loadingtext">
        <span>L</span>
        <span>o</span>
        <span>a</span>
        <span>d</span>
        <span>i</span>
        <span>n</span>
        <span>g</span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Now the first one returns the text, but the spacing is very small. The second one returns the same text, but the spacing is much larger. I have used both codes in the same browser, and the spacing is completely different. Why is this happening?

`loadingtext` is a custom loading screen made in only CSS used from [here](http://codepen.io/xixao/pen/jvxFc/).

Comment: Which browser?? is it the same result if you set the `innerHtml` before you set the `className`?

Comment: The second one has whitespace between the `span` elements, the first one doesn't

Comment: @JamesThorpe where is the whitespace? Please show.

Comment: @Varun every `span` tag has two spaces before it in your posted code

Comment: [See here for the difference it makes](http://jsfiddle.net/2vztrqyx/)

Comment: @JamesThorpe wow didn't realize this. Thank You! How do I fix this though?

Answer (score 1):

It can be because of the white-space. Try giving `font-size:0` to `h1` and your desired `font-size` to the `span` inside `h1`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/412/

```
h1{font-size:0}
h1 span{font-size:24px;}
```

There are also different ways to handle white-space issue. Search on SO for another options.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem. Thanks to James, I added the character

```
\n
```

To each of the `<span>` tags and it fixed the problem.

Thanks again for all the help!